# InfoPath Hyperlink with field data

Tags: infopath

Hi there hopefully someone can help.

Is there any way of putting a hyperlink into an InfoPath form which picks up data from an ID Field.  The ID Field is important as this ensures that the hyperlink navigates to the appropriate project page.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you get it working? Did my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the value of a hyperlink control

1. Right-click on the field that the hyperlink control is bound to in the **Fields** task pane.
2. Click **Properties**.
3. Enter the desired URL in the **Value** box.

**Note:**  You can use an XPath expression to calculate a dynamic hyperlink. For more information, see [Add Formulas and Functions in InfoPath 2010](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-Formulas-and-Functions-in-InfoPath-2010-a14c7efd-9884-4e09-9435-7e683666e7e5).

[image]

Comment: If my answer helps you than please mark it so others can get benefit of it... Thanks

Comment: Sorry it added a comment before I had chance to finish it - sadly it didn't work - I do however seem to be almost there by following a similar principal from Insert Formula - by adding the link and then inserting the ID field but at present it doesn't navigate back to the Project information as I expected.  The link I am entering is /sites/projects/Lists/PMO%20Project%20List/MikeDisplay.aspx?ID=ID   The ID at the end is the ID field (three digits).  Still doesn't navigate back to the three digits though.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get the hyperlink in the form?.. Please Check it once for me & let me know

Comment: Have you got the URL in your hyperlink field inside infopath form?